# Data Binding to an Injected Shared Model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to learn Angular alone, and want to pick up the Factory Method. I have defined an app and what I think is a factory like so:

```
var app = angular.module("MyPlayground", []);

app.factory('sharedModel', [

function() {
  var sharedModel = {
    config: {
      name: "My Playground",
      number: 123
    }
  };
  return sharedModel;
}
]);
```

I then have defined a controller like so:

```
  var MainController = function($scope, sharedModel) {
    console.log(sharedModel);
    $scope = sharedModel;
    console.log($scope);
    console.log($scope.config);
    console.log($scope.config.name);
  }
  MainController.$inject = ['$scope', 'sharedModel'];

  app.controller('MainController', MainController);
```

When I run this I can see in the console my object and it has properties called config, inside of which is the name and number specified.

Then, in my HTML I want to call up the name, so I try this:

`<h1>{{ config.name }}</h1>`

But all I can see is a blank screen. No errors in the console and with that plentiful usage of console.log I can see my value in the console OK as $scope.config.name

I even tried [following a simple tutorial on thinkster.io](https://thinkster.io/egghead/sharing-data-between-controllers/) but got "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined", so perhaps not as simple then...

I've been doing this on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tGcXGnWCSefk9QMYAkEC) if that helps see what I mean. Would appreciate any insight into this - just want to get my head around it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think overriding $scope is a good idea. Why don't make things simple?

```
  var MainController = function($scope, sharedModel) {
    console.log(sharedModel);
    $scope.sharedModel = sharedModel; 
    $scope.config =  sharedModel.config;
  }
```

Comment: Ah, I think I am starting to get it now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Variables you access from the html part should be in $scope. The idea is that the html part don't need an explicit declaration of $scope. However, when you write js code, you must use it.